# first boot or nvram reset condition

Tags: bios, clevo

a buddy of mine has a clevo nh55dc. Every time he turns on the computer, if the computer have been unplugged from the AC adapter (even with the battery in) a bios message comes up. "A first boot or nvram reset condition..." and an OK button. Before the message the machine seems to reboots itself, like it is reloading the settings. If he never disconnects the AC adapter the message never shows up.

We have replaced the CMOS battery with a new one, thinking that this would be the problem, but it did not solve it.

Interesting is that when we replaced the CMOS battery the date as expected was reset to 2019/01/01, but when the problem happens the date is not reset to 2019, it only seems that it loses some minutes, like if the clock stopped.

We installed three different versions of BIOS just to see if that would happen, but nothing changed.

Can't figure out what might be going on, what else can cause such behaviour if not the CMOS battery?

Comment: I assume a new CMOS battery was used, instead of a new user battery, to replace the original failing battery. What was the date of manufacture of the new battery?

Comment: a brand new Duracell battery, right from the store. What tells me that it is not the CMOS battery is the fact that the date does not reset to 2019 like it did when we took the old battery out. If it was the CMOS battery should the date not reset instead of simply "pause time"?

Comment: Something is wrong with the motherboard, it should keep bios settings (nvram) without ac and a charged battery installed.

Answer (score 0):

Motherboard had issues. Had to be replaced.